# Throttling Ember Data requests

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, throttling

I’m using Ember Data to interact with a REST API that has a rate limit.

Any suggestions for how to go about throttling Ember Data requests to X requests per second?

Comment: I would check out `ember-concurrency`. If you put your AJAX request in a task (in your adapter) it shouldnt be that hard I think.

Comment: `ember-concurrency` can limit by the number of concurrent requests. But I don't see how to limit it by a time constraint -- for example, no more than 5 requests per minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want to do things with *all* AJAX requests I strongly recommend `ember-ajax`. This gives you a single point to modify all your AJAX requests. Next about throttling. I suggested `ember-concurrency` In the comments, so let me elaborate this. `ember-concurrency` gives you a `timeout` method, that returns a promise that will resolve after a certain amount of time. This allows easy throtteling:

```
export default AjaxService.extend({
  ajaxThrottle: task(function * (cb) {
    cb();
    // maxConcurrency with timeout 1000 means at maximum 3 requests per second.
    yield timeout(1000);
  }).maxConcurrency(3).enqueue(),
  async request() {
    await new Promise(cb => ajaxThrottle.perform(cb));
    return this._super(...arguments); // this should make the actual request
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After some effort, I managed to get [promise-throttle](https://github.com/JMPerez/promise-throttle) to work within my `ApplicationController`. To limit to 4 requests per second:

```
import PromiseThrottle from 'dispatcher/application/promise-throttle';
import { Promise } from 'rsvp';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
  init() {
    this.set('promiseThrottle', new PromiseThrottle({
      requestsPerSecond: 4,
      promiseImplementation: Promise
    }));
  },
  ajax: function (url, type, options) {
    return this.get('promiseThrottle').add(this._super.bind(this, url, type, options));
  }
  ...
});
```